# For Google Workspace Admin SDK ReportsAPI, is response ordered by time

Tags: google-admin-sdk

For the [Activities](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) API, is response sorted by time specifically [id.time](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list#activity) ?

If not is there a way we can do that?

Comment: Yes it was and thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

At least when I test this, the activities are sorted by `id.time`, with more recent activities listed first.

No official documentation makes this explicit, though, so this behavior could change without notice.

#### Feature request:

I'd suggest you to file a feature request in Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191635&template=824102) in order to add query parameters to explicitly sort activities based on their time, and either in ascending or descending order.

#### Side note:

Also, depending on your situation, `startTime` and `endTime` might be useful, in order to filter activities based on their time.